# Where to search for more specific information about actions used in Siri Shortcuts app?

Tags: ios, siri, shortcuts-app

There is a nice user guide on Shortcuts by Apple https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios,  but there should be somewhere  some more datailed information as for example: what Pattern parameters may be used in "Match Text" action? Just some more precise definitions on Actions that may be used in the shortcuts. Anyone can help pointing to the right direction?

Comment: I've been looking at shortcuts that other people have created and open up the steps and go through those to get a better understanding of what each step means. Have you been to Reddit? They have a sub called Shortcuts. There are a thousand shortcuts posted by users there that you can learn from, if that is helpful.

Comment: that is exactly what I did and found in some posted shortcut someone used "Match text" action with pattern parameters of ^\w\b but would like to know what other parameters may be used witj this action and more detailed info on other actions as well, that would be so nice ...

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a good resource page on Siri shortcuts...

https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9k0sup/siri_shortcuts_resources/

And here’s the link you are looking for...

http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp

Also a great site for learning and testing regexp

https://regex101.com

And a great beginners video to get started

https://youtu.be/sa-TUpSx1JA